Mesh Analysis - 4 variables

I'm working on this problem, and got stuck. The question is asking what i0 is.
For Mesh 1:
-16+4(i_1-i_3 )+2(i_1-i_2 )=0
6i_1 - 2i_2 - 4i_3 = 16
For Mesh 2:
2(i_2 - i_1) + 8(i_2 - i_3) -10i_o = 0
-2i_1 +10i_2 - 8i_3 - 10i_o = 0
For Mesh 3:
4(i_3 - i_1) + 6i_3 + 8(i_3 - i_2) = 0
-4i_1 - 8i_2 + 18i_3 = 0
Since I have 3 equations, and 4 variables, I'm a little unsure on how to solve this problem. Suggestions?

i_0 is the same as i_3.

The Photon is telling you exactly what you use in order to have four equations and four unknowns. The fourth equation is \$I_0=I_3\$.
Using freely available SymPy and going clockwise for the mesh loops:
R1 = 4*RX
R2 = 2*RX
R3 = 8*RX
R4 = 6*RX
Loop1 = Eq( 0 + V1 - R1*(I1-I3) - R2*(I1-I2), 0 )
Loop2 = Eq( 0 - R2*(I2-I1) - R3*(I2-I3) + 10*I0, 0 )
Loop3 = Eq( 0 - R4*I3 - R3*(I3-I2) - R1*(I3-I1), 0 )
Assign1 = Eq( I0, I3 )
solve( [ Loop1, Loop2, Loop3, Assign1 ], [ I0, I1, I2, I3 ])
{I0: V1/(6*RX - 10),
 I1: (29*RX*V1 - 20*V1)/(84*RX**2 - 140*RX),
 I2: (17*RX*V1 + 10*V1)/(84*RX**2 - 140*RX),
 I3: V1/(6*RX - 10)}

Obviously, you know that \$V_1=10\:\text{V}\$ so you could just substitute that in and have only functions of \$R_x=R\$.
The missing equation is just what The Photon wrote in a short comment to you. That's all there was to remedying your quandary.

Using node voltage analysis it is a one-node problem.
(I would like someone to explain why it is ever worth knowing mesh analysis.)
